# Making OpenWeather API call from Android App

Tags: java, android, api, url

Now, I am trying to fetch weather information using the `OpenWeatherMap` API for my Android Application.

1. The return data format must be `json`
2. The unit must be in `metric`
3. I'd like to collect data for `7` days

Note that this is a part of Android development course by Udacity. In their sample code, the `API` query URL is being constructed as below:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;

String forecastJsonStr = null;
String format = "json";
String units = "metric";
int numDays = 7;

try
{
    final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =  "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
    final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
    final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
    final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
    final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
    .build();

    URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

}
```

While it works, in my newbie eyes, it was a lot of work just to generate simple query string. So, I am thinking, since I am not going to change any of the parameters in this query string, why can't I just use a simple string like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7")
```

Will there be any significant drawback in doing this way? Or is it something I should avoid doing?

Answer (score 0):

It was designed from the broader view as there might be change in the parameters in future as per the project need like currently the URL needs to be appended with the API key else the call wont be successful. now if you keep the static URL then you can change the location for which you need to fetch the weather data it wont be that you always want to fetch the data of the same location the user might want to fetch the data for other location in that how will your solution of keeping constant URL work?

So it's always good to keep design the solution in a such way that in future whenever you wish to add some new feature related to it the existing solution is inline with it.So it better to avoid doing such things like keeping the constant URL.

Hope it clear your thoughts.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me for a free account. Here I have used simple URL as given in their documentation. For forecast I get 5 day data. For current weather condition I get all required data. You can see those two URLs in my code.

```
public class RemoteFetch {

private static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_CURRENT = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%s&units=metric";
private static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_FORCAST = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=%s&units=metric";
private static Constants mC=new Constants();

public static JSONObject getJSON(Context context, String city, int dataType){
    try {
        String urlString=new String();

        if(dataType == mC.DATA_TYPE_CURRENT) {
            urlString=OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_CURRENT;
        }
        else if(dataType== mC.DATA_TYPE_FORCAST){
            urlString=OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_FORCAST;
        }
        URL url =new URL(String.format(urlString, city));


        HttpURLConnection connection =
                (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key",
                context.getString(R.string.open_weather_maps_app_id));

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
        String tmp="";
        while((tmp=reader.readLine())!=null)
            json.append(tmp).append("\n");
        reader.close();

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());

        // This value will be 404 if the request was not
        // successful
        if(data.getInt("cod") != 200){
            return null;
        }

        return data;
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

}